# How to use np.random.randint() to roll n dice, noting that each has a potentially different number of faces denoted by a vector f

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability, dice

I am trying to simulate the single roll of *n* dice, where each of the die can potentially have *f* faces. For example, if  =[2,5,7], then three dice with 2, 5 and 7 faces are rolled. Thank you!

Comment: The answers to this [similar though not identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067311/python-roll-dice-with-2-parameters-number-of-sides-of-the-dice-and-the-number-o) may help.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, however unfortunately the question does not resolve my issue, i.e. generating random rolls for a vector of faces.

Comment: This requires iterating through a list, generating a random number in a specified range, and addition.  These are all fairly simple operations.  Is there one of them you don't know how to do?  Or do you not know how to combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with this:

```
    f=[3,4,5]
    outcomes= []
    for i in f:
        out = 1 + np.random.randint(i, size = len(f) )
        outcomes.append(out)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without an explicit loop.  In this example, I'll use the "new" numpy random API that was introduced in numpy 1.17.  In the new API, random integers are generated with the `integers` method of the generator; it corresponds to the old `randint` method:

```
In [22]: rng = np.random.default_rng()                                          

In [23]: f = np.array([2, 5, 7])                                                

In [24]: rng.integers(1, f + 1)                                                 
Out[24]: array([2, 4, 6])
```

To repeat the process `n` times in one call, use the `size` argument:

```
In [30]: n = 8                                                                  

In [31]: rng.integers(1, f + 1, size=(n, 3))                                    
Out[31]: 
array([[1, 3, 4],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [2, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 2],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [2, 1, 7]])
```